# Issues with page processors in Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am using page processors to use some dynamic data on some pages. I have successfully used this on some URL like 'test' but when I try to use it on home page it doesn't work.

```
Code :

Working  ->

@processor_for("test")
def page_slug_processor(request, page):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/events/")

Doesn't work ->

@processor_for("/")
def page_slug_processor(request, page):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/events/")

Can someone tell me the correct way to do this .
```

Thanks

**Edit :**

Actually first one is working fine but in second case it doesn't work means I don't know whether that processor is called or not because it doesn't print anything , neither raise any error or Exception , So I doubted that it doesn't read the home slug or may be I have defined it in wrong way. Basically my requirement is to run a page processor on home URl ("/").

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: no , I think it doesn't call the function

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing exactly? Mezzanine is not a very well documented library, so you'll need to be a bit more specific for people to help you.

Comment: okay I'll edit my question.

Comment: Are both functions in the same file? If not, are you actually importing `processor_for` into both files?

Comment: I have edited my question. And I have defined only one processor but when I changed it to "test" it work and for "/" this it doesn't work and I have import processor_for else it would raise an error.

Comment: Can you try passing a blank string, i.e., `@processor_for("")`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43306/discussion-between-inforian-and-zeantsoi)

Answer (score 1):

Look in your **urls.conf**. You will see that by default mezzanine does not generate a normal page for the homepage, but instead assumes it will be static.

Simply edit your project's **urls.conf** to use the `HOMEPAGE AS AN EDITABLE PAGE IN THE PAGE TREE` option, and read the associated comments in the file.